# Bootstrap3: What is the correct way to resize the top-fixed navbar height to below 50px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to set navbar height to `45 px`. Default height of navbar is `50px`.

I change bootstrap.css

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

to

```
 .navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

But now there is small gap under the navbar(navbar-fixed-top). What is the correct way to resize the nav bar height to 45 px?

Comment: change some padding/margin properties of the navbar elements

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your own version of Bootstrap with custom values. It’ll automatically adapt all the children to fit the navbar height you chose.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-navbar